# How do i format time in Go Language

Tags: time, go, date-conversion

I need to format time like this

```
Mon, 16 Jun 2014 09:19:01 +0200
```

following code

```
a := time.RFC1123Z
```

give me

```
Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700
```

which seem correct but need current time and use now() somehow i guess. but havent figured out how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`Format`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) for this. [`time.RFC1123Z`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants) is just a layout string.

```
t := time.Now()
s := t.Format(time.RFC1123Z) // Format t to a string using the given layout
fmt.Println(s)
```